# CALayer: create broken ellipse with round edges?

Tags: ios, uikit, calayer

Here is my code to add an elliptic `CALayer` to a `UIView`:

```
let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
circleLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2),
                                radius: frame.size.width / 2,
                                startAngle: -.pi / 2,
                                endAngle: .pi / 6,
                                clockwise: false).cgPath
circleLayer.lineWidth = 8.0
circleLayer.cornerRadius = 4.0
circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
circleLayer.lineJoin = .round
squareView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
squareView.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
```

The result I get :

[image]

However, I would like to get this result instead:

[image]

Could you help me getting this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your line caps round, simply tell your shape layer to use round line caps:

```swift
circleLayer.lineCap = .round
```